# Excel VBA - Master List

Tags: excel, vba

Need Excel VBA help.

have an excel worksheet with a Master Tab and a Template Tab. I want to create automatic tabs from the master list the the template tab created. I am looking for a macro please. Tab Name A1, hyperlink A1. I also want A1-O1 to be copied to the new tab.

This is the macro I started with :

```
Sub CreateAndNameWorksheets()

    Dim c As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each c In Sheets("Master").Range("A1:A50")
        Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        With c
            ActiveSheet.Name = .Value
            .Parent.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=c, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
                    "'" & .Text & "'!A1", TextToDisplay:=.Text
        End With
    Next c
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please share code the demonstrate what you have already attempted. It is difficult for users to provide solutions without all the context.

Comment: I have an excel worksheet with a Master Tab and a Template Tab.  I want to create automatic tabs from the master list the the template tab created.  I am looking for a macro please.  Tab Name A1, hyperlink A1.  I also want A1-Z

Comment: sorry.  I also want A1-O1 to be copied to the new tab.

Comment: This is the macro I started with

Comment: Sub CreateAndNameWorksheets()
    Dim c As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each c In Sheets("Master").Range("A1:A50")
        Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        With c
            ActiveSheet.Name = .Value
            .Parent.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=c, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
                "'" & .Text & "'!A1", TextToDisplay:=.Text
        End With
    Next c
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub